# Is there any way to copy Haskell binaries to another project to save time on initial build?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cardano, plutus

I'm working on learning to build DApps on Cardano with Plutus, which is built in Haskell.
I've found that the initial cabal build for a project takes quite a long time, usually 30+ minutes, even if the cabal packages are cached on my local machine already.

Is there a way to copy the built Cardano/Plutus binaries from one project to another?

For example, can I just copy the contents of the dist-newstyle folder from a project that's already built into a new project that uses the same package dependencies? Or will that mess up the build on the new project?

TIA,
Marcel